# AVD manager cannot create a virtual device in QT creator

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to make an android app, but confronted an issue (“AVD manager ui tool is not available in the installed sdk tools. Use the command line tool avdmanager for advanced avd management" ) when I click the "start AVD manager" button in QT creator 4.4.1.

My operating platform is Window 10. Someone said that using lower level of sdk tool will help to solve this problem. But I don't know how to do that. In android studio, it only provides the 26.1 verison of sdk tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try replacing the sdk tools package. Here is a list of them:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html
Find an earlier version, and replace it in your sdk folder.

Comment: I remember having a similar problem, and replacing it did fix it. I just can't remember which version I replaced it with. Try maybe 25.2.2

Comment: I had the same problem. I found the solve. Just watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2s9NT60UIQ
You have to instal image for your AVD from the command line use avdmanager and sdkmanager.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tao_76 says.

Have you ever install a system image with SDK manager?

You can install it just in Qt's options dialog, "Device" page. (your second picture)

Install `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Image` recommand.

And do not forget enable Intel's virtual tech in BIOS.

Good luck :D